# Get a expensive donut for 75% off!

Tags: mathematics, visual, steganography

You are going to a donut store, which donuts are more than 500 dollars. The most fancy one is the Donut Dedeluxe, which cost 5000 dollars.

Luckily, they have a 75% off which is now 1,250. But, you must hear the manager first.

They are gonna say a random sentence and you must answer a number. After you answer with the correct answer, you buy the donut for 75% off.

Here are examples for some sentences and answers.

> Much art reuses themes and motifs from previous eras. They say: $14679808$
>
> Sure, its fancy and all. They say: $65535$
>
> My brother's car lets out a strange noise. They say: $16720896$
>
> I find I go too hard on her sometimes. They say: $4915330$
>
> Don't waste a lot of money. They say: $32896$

Now you are up on the list. The manager says:

> Leave the generic rims on it.
>
> You say : $15987355?$
>
> Sorry, but that's wrong.

So as always,

**Question:** What is the answer and why?

Hint 1:

> The tags looks suspicious but correct...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the core of the puzzle mechanism, down to the exact sentences used, appear to be plagiarized from [here](https://www.rd.com/list/brain-games/) (Scroll to "Hidden Hues")

Comment: I was dithering over the wording of that close reason for a while, as [Lukas Rotter](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57636681#57636681) alerted me to the plagiarism in chat before an answer posted.

Comment: @bobble - only downside of being closed is I might never get to know what the intended canonical source of the mapping was supposed to be - e.g. why dfff00 rather than 7fff00 - or indeed what the donut-related clues, numbers, prices, etc. were supposed to lead to. Curious minds will remain curious.

Comment: Comments and edits aren't disabled, just answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple answers seem to be valid, for example

> The intended answer is probably $14423100$, but other answers such as
>  $10027008$ or $15014476$ may be accepted, depending on the precise acceptance criteria.

It seems that the question was in fact missing a tag, as I needed to make use of

> [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge)

to arrive at the answer process which was:

> Each "random" sentence has a colour name hidden in it, and the number is the 6-digit hexadecimal color code converted to decimal, so a suitable database of color codes to colour names is required. Many resources for this exist online, and it's very unclear which one was intended.

Perhaps the flavour text about the donuts

> Gives some clues about a specific source of colour names that "should" be used.

Taking the clues given:

- > Mu***ch art reuse***s themes and motifs from previous eras: 14679808 => DFFF00, which is one of many colour codes described as "Chartreuse" online - e.g. https://encycolorpedia.com/dfff00 - the top google match for dfff00, and I've used the same example site for other links below...
- > Sure, its fan***cy an***d all: 65535 => 00FFFF, which is the a cyan at maximum saturation. https://encycolorpedia.com/00ffff
- > My brother'***s car let***s out a strange noise: 16720896 => FF2400, described as "Scarlet" https://encycolorpedia.com/ff2400
- > I f***ind I go*** too hard on her sometimes: 4915330 => 4B0082, described as "Indigo" https://encycolorpedia.com/4b0082
- > Don't waste a lot of money: 32896 => 008080, a medium-dark shade of Cyan, also referred to as "Teal" https://encycolorpedia.com/008080

For the "wrong" answer given:

> 15987355 => F3F29B, this corresponds with an unnamed light shade of yellow https://encycolorpedia.com/f3f29b
>  The hidden word, however, is "Crimson"
>  Leave the generi***c rims on*** it.

Correct answers

> should resolve to color codes that include the hidden colour name in their description

for example (explaining the examples given at the start of this answer):

- > 14423100 => DC143C described as "Crimson" at https://encycolorpedia.com/dc143c
- > 10027008 => 990000 described as "Crimson red" at https://encycolorpedia.com/990000
- > 15014476 => E51A4C described as "Spanish Crimson" at https://encycolorpedia.com/e51a4c